# Calculation with Latex

Tags: calculations

I am currently trying to create an exam template for my institute. What I want to receive is like this:

---

Task 1 [8 Points]

(text text text)

Subtask 1.1 [3 Points]

(text text text)

Subask 1.2 [5 Points]

(text text text)

---

And the [8 Points] of Task 1 is actually the result of the subtasks 3+5 Points.

I've been trying to tackle this thing with the package 'calculator'. The problem was to update the final result of the task. Here is my short Latex script:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{calculator}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\res}{0}
\section{First Task [\res\, Points]}
\newcommand{\temp}{5}
\subsection{[\temp\, Points]}
\lipsum[1]
\ADD{\res}{\temp}{\res}
\renewcommand{\temp}{8}
\subsection{[\temp \,Points]}
\lipsum[1]
\ADD{\res}{\temp}{\res}
\end{document}
```

Thank you very much for your ideas!

Comment: There are packages that do such things automatically for you, for example the `exercise` package. See https://www.ctan.org/topic/exam for an overview of related packages.

Answer (score 3):

There are many packages available for this kind of task (see https://www.ctan.org/topic/exam), but if you want to do it manually, you can use the `xcntperchap` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcntperchap}
\usepackage{multido}

\newcounter{points}
\RegisterCounters{section}{points}
\RegisterCounters{subsection}{points}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\newcounter{totalsubsection}
\xpretocmd{\subsection}{\stepcounter{totalsubsection}}{}{}


\begin{document}


\section{Sectiona \ObtainTrackedValueExp{section}{points}}

\subsection{subsectiona \ObtainTrackedValueExp[\value{totalsubsection}]{subsection}{points} }
\multido{}{2}{\refstepcounter{points}}

\subsection{subsectionb \ObtainTrackedValueExp[\value{totalsubsection}]{subsection}{points} }
\multido{}{3}{\refstepcounter{points}}


\section{Sectionb \ObtainTrackedValueExp{section}{points}}

\subsection{subsectionc \ObtainTrackedValueExp[\value{totalsubsection}]{subsection}{points} }
\multido{}{1}{\refstepcounter{points}}


\subsection{subsectiond \ObtainTrackedValueExp[\value{totalsubsection}]{subsection}{points} }
\multido{}{2}{\refstepcounter{points}}

\end{document}
```